# Wireless confusion

Tags: wireless, networking

I have 14e4:4306 rev 02 Broadcom wireless adapter. Lubuntu detects the card but I can't get wireless I installed the firmware (just in case) nothing happened rfkill does nothing but rfkill help does

I just want wireless internet.
Please explain step by step I've been using (l) ubuntu for 2 days.

Comment: Please run the script that is in the accepted answer in the link below so we may see the information needed to help diagnose the issue.
<http://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-can-i-do>